# Composite indexes with RavenDB

Tags: c#, .net, ravendb

I'm trying to create a composite index using RavenDB. Basically, I have 2 models that I need "joined" and able to perform searches on the result.

Here's an example of my models:

Model 1:

```
public class UserProfile {
    public string ProfileId { get; set }
    public string FirstName { get; set }
    public string LastName { get; set }
    public string EmailAddress { get; set }
}
```

Model 2:

```
public class UserProjects {
    public string UserProjectId { get; set }
    public List<Project> Projects { get; set }
}
```

Here's the Project Model, in case you're wondering:

```
public class Project {
    public string ProjectId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

The `UserProjectId` property is as follows: `users/<Email Address>/projects`.

I was able to create an index that returns all the fields, but I'm not able to search on certain fields.

Here's my index:

```
public class ProfileProjectIndex : AbstractIndexCreationTask<UserProfile> {
    Map = profiles =>
        from profile in profiles
        select new {
            profile.ProfileId,
            profile.FirstName,
            profile.LastName,
            profile.EmailAddress
        };

    TransformResults = (db, results) =>
        from result in results
        let project = db.Load<UserProjects>("users/" + profile.EmailAddress + "/projects")
        select new {
            result.ProfileId,
            result.EmailAddress,
            result.FirstName,
            result.LastName,
            project.UserProjectId,
            project.Projects
        };
}
```

Now this index, when querying Raven from the web interface, returns the complete list of data I could want, but I need to be able to filter the results based on some values included in the `UserProjects.Projects` list, for example:

return all user profiles with associated projects when `Project.Projects.Contains(x => x.ProjectId == "projects/1234")`

Any RavenDB gurus can enlighten me? Oh, and I'm using RavenDB 2.5.

Answer (score 0):

You are probably looking at multi map indexes, see:

http://ravendb.net/docs/article-page/3.0/csharp/indexes/multi-map-indexes

Comment: I looked into multi map indexes and all they do is create an index with all the mapped entities in it, they don't combine them together.

Comment: You can then use a reduce to group them together

Comment: How? I wasn't able to write a reduce function that would associate both documents together.